# How to prevent the history from disappearing in Calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a FreeCodeCamp Calculator. It's almost finished. I just need to polish up several things. However, the main problem that is bothering me is why did the history area disappear when I press a number...

I tried to code the calculator in a way in which one person presses several numbers, and then presses a operator such as "x", "+", etc, the number already entered moves down to the history area. I've noticed that when I click on more than one number, the zero disappears. It's also the same for when I click on a decimal ".". In the case of the decimals, in first scenario, if I press ".", the zero didn't disappear but then I press a number, the zero disappears. In second scenario, if I press a number first, and then press a decimal, the zero disappears.

How do I fix it?

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var mainMath = "0";
  var subMath = "0";
  var reset = "";
  update();
  
  $("button").click(function(){
    calculate($(this).attr("value"));
  });
  
  function calculate(keyitem) {
    switch(keyitem) {
      case "clear":
        clearScreen();
        break;
      case "plusminus":
        plusminusScreen();
        break;
      case "%":
        percentageScreen();
        break;
      case "/":
      case "*":
      case "+":
      case "-":
        addOperator(keyitem);
        break;
      case "0":
      case "1":
      case "2":
      case "3":
      case "4":
      case "5":
      case "6":
      case "7":
      case "8":
      case "9":
        addNumber(keyitem);
        break;
      case ".":
        addDecimal(keyitem);
        break;
      case "=":
        solveEqual();
        break;
    }
    update();
    };
 
  function clearScreen() {
     mainMath = "0";
     subMath = "0";
  };
  
  function plusminusScreen() {
     mainMath = -1 * mainMath;
  };
  
  function addNumber(keyitem) {
    /*if (keyitem == "."){
      if(mainMath == "0") {
        mainMath = "0" + keyitem;
        return;
      } 
    }*/
    if (mainMath == "0"){
      mainMath = keyitem;
      return;
    }
    if (subMath == "0") {
      subMath = "";
    }
    mainMath+=keyitem;
  };
  
  function addOperator(keyitem){
    if(mainMath == "0"){
    subMath += "0";
    }
    addNumber(keyitem);
    subMath += mainMath;
    mainMath = "0";
  };
  
  function addDecimal(keyitem){
    if (keyitem == "."){
      if(mainMath == "0") {
        mainMath = "0" + keyitem;
        subMath = "0";
        return;
      } 
    }
    addNumber(keyitem);
  };
  
  function solveEqual() {
    mainMath = eval(subMath+mainMath);
  };
  
  function update(){
  $("#answer").html(mainMath);
  $("#history").html(subMath);
};
  
  
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400');
h1, h2, h3, p {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
html, body{
  height:100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  padding: 160px 0;
}
.calculatorbox {
  width: 260px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.calheader {
  text-align: center;
}
.calwindow {
  background: #000000;
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-direction: column; /* Safari */
  flex-direction:         column;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding: 10px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.entry {
  font-size: 4em;
  display: block;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.entryhistory {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.entry p, .entryhistory p {
  margin: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}
sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}
 
sub {
  bottom: -0em;
}
.row {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.key {
  width: 65px;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 22px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.key.btnspan {
  width: 130px;
}
.key.topcolor {
  background: #d9d9d9;
}
.key.orange {
  background: #ff8c00;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="calheader">
      <h2>Simple Calculator</h2>
    </div>
  <div class="calculatorbox">
    <div class="calwindow">
      <!-- ENTRY BOX -->
      <div class="entry">
        <p id="answer">0</p>
      </div>
      <div class="entryhistory">
        <p id="history">0</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- BUTTONS -->
    <div class="calbuttons">
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key topcolor" value="clear">C</button>
        <button class="key topcolor" value="plusminus"><sup>+</sup>/<sub>−</sub></button>
        <button class="key topcolor" value="%">%</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="/">÷</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key" value="7">7</button>
        <button class="key" value="8">8</button>
        <button class="key" value="9">9</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="*">×</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key" value="4">4</button>
        <button class="key" value="5">5</button>
        <button class="key" value="6">6</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="-">−</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key" value="1">1</button>
        <button class="key" value="2">2</button>
        <button class="key" value="3">3</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="+">+</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key btnspan" value="0">0</button>
        <button class="key" value=".">.</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="=">=</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And a calculator should work with numbers...

Comment: @Jonasw, I don't understand what you are saying? Of course, Calculator should work with numbers, but you need to take in account decimals and negative numbers, which is part of the calculator. Therefore, you need to explain further what you mean by your comment.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, I don't think that update() is the problem. I think the problem lies with function addNumber(keyitem), function addOperator(keyitem), and function addDecimal(keyitem). Were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this zero problem!

Here's the solution in which I moved this code:

```
if(subMath == "0"){
      subMath = "";
    }
```

to `function addOperator();`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var mainMath = "0";
  var subMath = "0";
  var finalset = "";
  var finalresult = "";
  update();
  
  $("button").click(function(){
    calculate($(this).attr("value"));
  });
  
  function calculate(keyitem) {
    switch(keyitem) {
      case "clear":
        clearScreen();
        break;
      case "plusminus":
        plusminusScreen();
        break;
      case "%":
        percentageScreen();
        break;
      case "/":
      case "*":
      case "+":
      case "-":
        addOperator(keyitem);
        break;
      case "0":
      case "1":
      case "2":
      case "3":
      case "4":
      case "5":
      case "6":
      case "7":
      case "8":
      case "9":
        addNumber(keyitem);
        break;
      case ".":
        addDecimal(keyitem);
        break;
      case "=":
        solveEqual();
        break;
    }
    update();
    };
 
  function clearScreen() {
     mainMath = "0";
     subMath = "0";
  };
  
  function plusminusScreen() {
     mainMath = -1 * mainMath;
  };
  
  function addNumber(keyitem) {
    if (mainMath == "0"){
      mainMath = keyitem;
      finalset = mainMath;
      return;
    }
    /*if (subMath == "0") {
      subMath = "";
    }*/
    /*subMath = subMath.replace("0",keyitem)*/
    mainMath+=keyitem;
  };
  
  function addOperator(keyitem){
    if(mainMath == "0"){
      subMath += "0";
    }
    if(subMath == "0"){
      subMath = "";
    }
    addNumber(keyitem);
    subMath += mainMath;
    mainMath = "0";
  };
  
  function addDecimal(keyitem){
    if (keyitem == "."){
      if(mainMath == "0") {
        mainMath = "0" + keyitem;
        subMath = "0";
        return;
      } 
    }
    addNumber(keyitem);
  };
  
  function solveEqual() {
    mainMath = eval(subMath+mainMath);
    subMath += finalset;
  };
  
  function update(){
  $("#answer").html(mainMath);
  $("#history").html(subMath);
};
  
  
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400');
h1, h2, h3, p {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
html, body{
  height:100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  padding: 160px 0;
}
.calculatorbox {
  width: 260px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.calheader {
  text-align: center;
}
.calwindow {
  background: #000000;
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-direction: column; /* Safari */
  flex-direction:         column;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding: 10px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.entry {
  font-size: 4em;
  display: block;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.entryhistory {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.entry p, .entryhistory p {
  margin: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}
sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}
 
sub {
  bottom: -0em;
}
.row {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.key {
  width: 65px;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 22px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.key.btnspan {
  width: 130px;
}
.key.topcolor {
  background: #d9d9d9;
}
.key.orange {
  background: #ff8c00;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="calheader">
      <h2>Simple Calculator</h2>
    </div>
  <div class="calculatorbox">
    <div class="calwindow">
      <!-- ENTRY BOX -->
      <div class="entry">
        <p id="answer"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="entryhistory">
        <p id="history"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- BUTTONS -->
    <div class="calbuttons">
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key topcolor" value="clear">C</button>
        <button class="key topcolor" value="plusminus"><sup>+</sup>/<sub>−</sub></button>
        <button class="key topcolor" value="%">%</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="/">÷</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key" value="7">7</button>
        <button class="key" value="8">8</button>
        <button class="key" value="9">9</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="*">×</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key" value="4">4</button>
        <button class="key" value="5">5</button>
        <button class="key" value="6">6</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="-">−</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key" value="1">1</button>
        <button class="key" value="2">2</button>
        <button class="key" value="3">3</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="+">+</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key btnspan" value="0">0</button>
        <button class="key" value=".">.</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="=">=</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```